# I downloaded Eclipse IDE for my developments and throws back this

Tags: java

so i tried to install my eclipse ide for my java projects development and gives me an error. Can some one please help me on this.
error below

[image]

Comment: check Java SDK is install in your system. And all the PATH variable are set.

Comment: Go for Intellij IDEA!:)

Comment: You need to make sure that your Eclipse finds the correct JDK (Version and 32/64 bit). In case of doubt, supply it with your JDK using the -vm parameter at startup.

Comment: Note that inside that error message it's says:
_... requiredJavaVersion=1.7...._
This simply means that eclipse cannot find the correct Java installation in your computer.
So you should check it, in most cases Java (jre & jdk) installed at `C:\Program Files\Java`

Comment: @NikitaKurtin That's the launch command, not the error message, which is only "exit code=2".